# How to create a schedule which triggers the runbook using PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm trying to create a schedule to trigger a runbook using PowerShell commands in Azure Automation account. Runbook is taking **resourcevariable** which is an automation variable as an input parameter.

I am able to create a schedule, but I am not able to register it as it is throwing the error:

> Invalid runbook parameters

How can I register it and trigger a runbook ?

My code:

```
$TimeZone = ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local).Id

$scheduleName = "newschedule1"

$automationAccountName = "SentinelAutomationAccount"

$resourcegroupName = "myrg"

$RunbookName = "runbook1"

$params = @{"resourcevariable" = $resourcevariable;"flag" = $false}

$starttime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(40)

$schedule = New-AzAutomationSchedule –AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName –Name $scheduleName –StartTime $starttime -OneTime -ResourceGroupName  $resourcegroupName -TimeZone $TimeZone

Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName -RunbookName $RunbookName -ScheduleName $scheduleName  -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupName -Parameters $params
```

**Runbook1 script: (5.1 version)**

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $resourcevariable
)
    # Login to Azure
    try
    {
        "Logging in to Azure..."
       Connect-AzAccount -Identity 
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
     
     $TimeZone = ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local).Id                                                                            
    $automationAccount = "xxxAutomationAccount"                                                                                
    $resourcegroup = "xxx"                                                                                
    $scheduleName = "myschedule"                                                                                           
    $Runbook = "xxxRunBook"        
    $params = @{"resourcevariable" = "resourcevariable";"flag" = "false"}                                                                                             
    $starttime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(40)                                                                                   
    $schedule = New-AzAutomationSchedule –AutomationAccountName $automationAccount –Name $scheduleName –StartTime $starttime -OneTime -ResourceGroupName  $resourcegroup -TimeZone $TimeZone
    Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName $automationAccount -RunbookName $Runbook -ScheduleName $scheduleName  -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Parameters $params.Parameters
```

**Runbook2 script: (7.1 version)**

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $resourcevariable
)
    # Login to Azure
    try
    {
        "Logging in to Azure..."
        Connect-AzAccount -Identity
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
    
    echo "From Runbook2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in my environment and found the same error.

***When trying to retrieve parameters stored in the params variable, we should specify them as*** `$params.parameters`.

*I modified the script and was able to correctly register and trigger the schedule.*

***Modified script:***

```
$params = @{"resourcevariable" = "resourcevariable";"flag" = "false"}
Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName $automationAccount -RunbookName $Runbook -ScheduleName $scheduleName  -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Parameters $params.Parameters
```

***myschedule.ps1:***

```
$TimeZone = ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local).Id                                                                            
$automationAccount = "xxxxautomationaccount"                                                                                
$resourcegroup = "xxxResourcegroup"                                                                                
$scheduleName = "xxxxxschedule"                                                                                           
$Runbook = "xxxxrunbook"        
$params = @{"resourcevariable" = "resourcevariable";"flag" = "false"}                                                                                             
$starttime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(40)                                                                                   
$schedule = New-AzAutomationSchedule –AutomationAccountName $automationAccount –Name $scheduleName –StartTime $starttime -OneTime -ResourceGroupName  $resourcegroup -TimeZone $TimeZone
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Scheduled in Portal successfully:***

[image]

**Note:** *Run the same script in runbook with the changes given above to get the same results.*

Comment: Hi Jahnavi edited the query in the above post. Tried calling runbook2 from runbook1 .. It is giving  this error : "Runbook mandatory parameter not specified. Parameter name resourceVariable." Is the resourceVariable used here is an automation variable ?

Comment: "Runbook mandatory parameter not specified":- It means you need to give `-runbook <runbookname>` parameter while calling the PowerShell command. @dev333

Comment: Hi Jahnavi .. gave all the required params to the powershell command. It is asking for resourcevariable param . In my case it is an automation variable. My latest code has been posted in two runbooks above

Comment: Did you add the resource variable in `variables -> shared resources -> automation account` in the portal?

Comment: Have created a resourcevariable in variables -> shared resources -> automation account. But not sure why it is giving this weird error

Comment: Remove params totally and try once! @dev333